How to view REST API requests to SharePoint Online
I am not seeing the GET requests to SharePoint Online REST API (_api/web/webs, _api/web/sitegroups etc.,) in the Audit Logs. Are these supposed to be present there, or is there an alternate way to get them?
Tried dumping the M365 Audit Logs, but am not seeing any entries corresponding to them. When requested from PowerBI for example, I can see the 'Power Query for Excel' in the Signin logs in Azure, but nothing shows up on the M365 Audit Logs corresponding to these...

By default, REST API GET requests to SharePoint online do not show in the Microsoft 365 audit logs.
